# How to replace efficiently newline characters in Mac

Tags: xcode, perl, character-encoding, newline

Someone in our development team merged in code but with windows newline characters. And git, merging tool get crazy about it. How is it possible to replace all `0D0A` -> `0A` in the whole Xcode project? If I do it in Xcode, Xcode crashed.

[image]

Comment: How are you doing it in xCode and which xCode version do you have?

Comment: Version 9.3 (9E145)

Comment: Did you try this http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=258025 ?

Comment: You could use the `dos2unix` tool

Comment: FYI - there is some help regarding this on github, which refreshes line endings on your repository (without the need for perl): https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/\r\n/\n/g;' *.h
perl -pi -w -e 's/\r\n/\n/g;' *.m
```